# State Machine in .NET framework

Tags: .net

I had discussion with some of my colleagues and I am confuse about discussion. Everyone said .NET framework stores IL code every time after compilation in something called "State Machine". However as per my knowledge I don't think so that every time State Machine comes in picture after compilation. I searched a lot on google but did not find anything authentic justification to understand State Machine concept. Is it true that when we compile code .Net framework always store IL code into "State Machine"?

Please Help.

Comment: "state machine" as a coding pattern, has little to do with "always store IL code", so the reason you didnt find much is i believe ur initial understanding is incorrect and hence you can find anything. coding up code in c# to follow a state machine pattern has nothing to do with " IL code" and has everything to do with how you go about structuring your code.

Comment: Please go through below link. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine   I think it probably comes in picture when we use async or await.

Comment: Specifically for "yield" and "await" a state machine code pattern is created, stored as IL. For "regular code" no state machine is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IL code is **not always** strucured as a state machine. Specifically, for the asynchronous semantics exposed by `yield`, `async` and `await`, code structured as a state machine **is** generated. Aside from that, no state machine is generated, neither required. However, if you code a state machine, then most likely the IL code generated will resemble a state machine, assuming optimizations don't change the underlying layout of the generated IL code.